# Better way to clean a string?

Tags: c#, asp.net, string, linq

I am using this method to clean a string:

```
public static string CleanString(string dirtyString)
{
    string removeChars = " ?&^$#@!()+-,:;<>’\'-_*";
    string result = dirtyString;

    foreach (char c in removeChars)
    {
        result = result.Replace(c.ToString(), string.Empty);
    }

    return result;
}
```

This method gives the correct result. However, there is a performance glitch in this method. Every time I pass the string, every character goes into the loop. If I have a large string then it will take too much time to return the object.

Is there a better way of doing the same thing? Maybe using LINQ or jQuery/JavaScript?

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: For what purpose are you `"cleaning"` a string?

Comment: i am basically dealing it with a lot of Qurystring values...

Comment: you just want to make a string null or what?

Comment: Put all characters in a character class of regex, then replace all at once.

Comment: explore `System.Text.RegularExpression` namespace for this

Comment: Could this be done with RegEx?

Comment: Define "better". Any solution will have a loop over the characters. The drawback in your code is excess creation of string objects, not the loop over every character.

Comment: I'm a little concerned about you "cleaning" a query string.  Can you describe what you are doing with the cleaned string?

Comment: so what do you suggest, which string objects i can remove?

Comment: there are values in querystring on which i have to build up <a href> tag...there are some cases in which i have values comeing from the database with the html tags included and want to show them on pages.

Comment: @patel.milanb - If you are using this to connect to a SQL database then your doing it wrong.

Comment: @patel.milanb Then what you are looking for is `HttpUtility.HtmlEncode` not string cleaning

Answer (score 52, accepted):

OK, consider the following test:

```
public class CleanString
{
    //by MSDN http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/844skk0h(v=vs.71).aspx
    public static string UseRegex(string strIn)
    {
        // Replace invalid characters with empty strings.
        return Regex.Replace(strIn, @"[^\w\.@-]", "");
    }

    // by Paolo Tedesco
    public static String UseStringBuilder(string strIn)
    {
        const string removeChars = " ?&^$#@!()+-,:;<>’\'-_*";
        // specify capacity of StringBuilder to avoid resizing
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(strIn.Length);
        foreach (char x in strIn.Where(c => !removeChars.Contains(c)))
        {
            sb.Append(x);
        }
        return sb.ToString();
    }

    // by Paolo Tedesco, but using a HashSet
    public static String UseStringBuilderWithHashSet(string strIn)
    {
        var hashSet = new HashSet<char>(" ?&^$#@!()+-,:;<>’\'-_*");
        // specify capacity of StringBuilder to avoid resizing
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(strIn.Length);
        foreach (char x in strIn.Where(c => !hashSet.Contains(c)))
        {
            sb.Append(x);
        }
        return sb.ToString();
    }

    // by SteveDog
    public static string UseStringBuilderWithHashSet2(string dirtyString)
    {
        HashSet<char> removeChars = new HashSet<char>(" ?&^$#@!()+-,:;<>’\'-_*");
        StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder(dirtyString.Length);
        foreach (char c in dirtyString)
            if (removeChars.Contains(c))
                result.Append(c);
        return result.ToString();
    }

    // original by patel.milanb
    public static string UseReplace(string dirtyString)
    {
        string removeChars = " ?&^$#@!()+-,:;<>’\'-_*";
        string result = dirtyString;

        foreach (char c in removeChars)
        {
            result = result.Replace(c.ToString(), string.Empty);
        }

        return result;
    }

    // by L.B
    public static string UseWhere(string dirtyString)
    {
        return new String(dirtyString.Where(Char.IsLetterOrDigit).ToArray());
    }
}

static class Program
{
    /// <summary>
    /// The main entry point for the application.
    /// </summary>
    [STAThread]
    static void Main()
    {
        var dirtyString = "sdfdf.dsf8908()=(=(sadfJJLef@ssyd€sdöf////fj()=/§(§&/(\"&sdfdf.dsf8908()=(=(sadfJJLef@ssyd€sdöf////fj()=/§(§&/(\"&sdfdf.dsf8908()=(=(sadfJJLef@ssyd€sdöf";
        var sw = new Stopwatch();

        var iterations = 50000;
        
        sw.Start();
        for (var i = 0; i < iterations; i++)
            CleanString.<SomeMethod>(dirtyString);
        sw.Stop();
        Debug.WriteLine("CleanString.<SomeMethod>: " + sw.ElapsedMilliseconds.ToString());
        sw.Reset();

        ....
        <repeat>
        ....       
    }
}
```

---

**Output**

```
CleanString.UseReplace: 791
CleanString.UseStringBuilder: 2805
CleanString.UseStringBuilderWithHashSet: 521
CleanString.UseStringBuilderWithHashSet2: 331
CleanString.UseRegex: 1700
CleanString.UseWhere: 233
```

---

**Conclusion**

It probably does not matter which method you use.

The difference in time between the fastest (`UseWhere`: 233ms) and the slowest (`UseStringBuilder`: 2805ms) method is 2572ms when called 50000 (!) times in a row. If you don't run the method that often, the difference does not really matter.

But if performance is critical, use the `UseWhere` method (written by L.B). Note, however, that its behavior is slightly different.

Comment: What would this give `return new String(dirtyString.Where(Char.IsLetterOrDigit).ToArray())` at your machine?

Comment: It's fast. 50000 iterations: 182ms (next one is `UseStringBuilderWithHashSet2` with 266ms)

Comment: Just for the reccords, for UseStringBuilderWithHashSet and UseStringBuilderWithHashSet2 the test will be 
`if (!removeChars.Contains(c))`

Comment: Can L.B's UseWhere method be extended to allow additional characters?

Like this:

        public static string UseWhereExtended(string dirtyString)
        {
            IEnumerable<char> stringQuery =
              from ch in dirtyString
              where char.IsLetterOrDigit(ch) ||
                ch == '.' ||
                ch == ',' ||
                ch == '\'' ||
                ch == '\"' ||
                ch == '?' ||
                ch == '!'
              select ch;

            return new string(stringQuery.ToArray());
        }

Comment: I think there's an error in `UseStringBuilderWithHashSet2`, shouldn't `if(removeChars.Contains(c))` be `if(!removeChars.Contains(c))`?

Answer (score 7):

If it's purely speed and efficiency you are after, I would recommend doing something like this:

```
public static string CleanString(string dirtyString)
{
    HashSet<char> removeChars = new HashSet<char>(" ?&^$#@!()+-,:;<>’\'-_*");
    StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder(dirtyString.Length);
    foreach (char c in dirtyString)
        if (!removeChars.Contains(c)) // prevent dirty chars
            result.Append(c);
    return result.ToString();
}
```

RegEx is certainly an elegant solution, but it adds extra overhead.  By specifying the starting length of the string builder, it will only need to allocate the memory once (and a second time for the `ToString` at the end).  This will cut down on memory usage and increase the speed, especially on longer strings.

However, as L.B. said, if you are using this to properly encode text that is bound for HTML output, you should be using `HttpUtility.HtmlEncode` instead of doing it yourself.

Comment: `removeChars.IndexOf` is `O(n)` operation . A `HashSet` would be better.

Comment: `output` should be `result`. Also you can omit `.ToCharArray()`, since a string implements `IEnumerable<char>`.

Comment: Grrr..  Thanks @BigYellowCactus.  Don't know how I missed that.

Comment: You can also use a one-liner `return new String(dirtyString.Where(c => !removeChars.Contains(c)).ToArray());`

Comment: how would you add white space to removeChars hashet?

Comment: @Qweick well, the space character is already included, but if there were any other white space characters that you wanted to include, you could just concatenate them to the string (e.g. "..." & vbTab).

Comment: @StevenDoggart grrh, yes, thanks :) For some reason I assumed there had to be a symbol for that :))

Answer (score 4):

use regex `[?&^$#@!()+-,:;<>’\'-_*]` for replacing with empty string

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if, performance-wise, using a `Regex` or LINQ would be an improvement.
Something that could be useful, would be to create the new string with a `StringBuilder` instead of using `string.Replace` each time:

```
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

static class Program {
    static void Main(string[] args) {
        const string removeChars = " ?&^$#@!()+-,:;<>’\'-_*";
        string result = "x&y(z)";
        // specify capacity of StringBuilder to avoid resizing
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(result.Length);
        foreach (char x in result.Where(c => !removeChars.Contains(c))) {
            sb.Append(x);
        }
        result = sb.ToString();
    }
}
```

Comment: this certainly helps. opens up a new idea for me using the StringBuilder class

Comment: `removeChars.Contains` is `O(n)`. A `HashSet` would be better.

Answer (score 2):

This one is even faster!
use:

```
string dirty=@"tfgtf$@$%gttg%$% 664%$";
string clean = dirty.Clean();


    public static string Clean(this String name)
    {
        var namearray = new Char[name.Length];

        var newIndex = 0;
        for (var index = 0; index < namearray.Length; index++)
        {
            var letter = (Int32)name[index];

            if (!((letter > 96 && letter < 123) || (letter > 64 && letter < 91) || (letter > 47 && letter < 58)))
                continue;

            namearray[newIndex] = (Char)letter;
            ++newIndex;
        }

        return new String(namearray).TrimEnd();
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Give this a try: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xwewhkd1.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps it helps to first explain the 'why' and then the 'what'. The reason you're getting slow performance is because c# copies-and-replaces the strings for each replacement. From my experience using Regex in .NET isn't always better - although in most scenario's (I think including this one) it'll probably work just fine.

If I really need performance I usually don't leave it up to luck and just tell the compiler exactly what I want: that is: create a string with the upper bound number of characters and copy all the chars in there that you need. It's also possible to replace the hashset with a switch / case or array in which case you might end up with a jump table or array lookup - which is even faster.

The 'pragmatic' best, but fast solution is:

```
char[] data = new char[dirtyString.Length];
int ptr = 0;
HashSet<char> hs = new HashSet<char>() { /* all your excluded chars go here */ };
foreach (char c in dirtyString)
    if (!hs.Contains(c))
        data[ptr++] = c;
return new string(data, 0, ptr);
```

BTW: this solution is incorrect when you want to process high surrogate Unicode characters - but can easily be adapted to include these characters.

-Stefan.

Answer (score 1):

I use this in my current project and it works fine. It takes a sentence, it removes all the non alphanumerical characters, it then returns the sentence with all the words in the first letter upper case and everything else in lower case. Maybe I should call it SentenceNormalizer. Naming is hard :)

```
    internal static string StringSanitizer(string whateverString)
{
    whateverString = whateverString.Trim().ToLower();
    Regex cleaner = new Regex("(?:[^a-zA-Z0-9 ])", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase | RegexOptions.CultureInvariant | RegexOptions.Compiled);
    var listOfWords = (cleaner.Replace(whateverString, string.Empty).Split(' ', StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)).ToList();
    string cleanString = string.Empty;
    foreach (string word in listOfWords)
    {
        cleanString += $"{word.First().ToString().ToUpper() + word.Substring(1)} ";
    }
    return cleanString;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not able to spend time on acid testing this but this line did not actually clean slashes as desired.

```
HashSet<char> removeChars = new HashSet<char>(" ?&^$#@!()+-,:;<>’\'-_*");
```

I had to add slashes individually and escape the backslash

```
HashSet<char> removeChars = new HashSet<char>(" ?&^$#@!()+-,:;<>’'-_*");
removeChars.Add('/');
removeChars.Add('\\');
```