# Automatically escape special characters entered in text box

Tags: c#, winforms, textbox

I'm programming with Win Forms and whatever a user puts in a text box is being converted WYSIWYG to a string, then sent via an Sqlcommand in the rough form of `Sqlcommand("INSERT INTO dbo.Call VALUES('" + textBox.Text + "');", Connection);` but if `textBox` contains a double quote, it'll screw with the formatting (this will probably happen with a single quote, backslash, etc). Is there an easy way to set Win Forms or code C# to automatically put `\` before these characters?

Comment: Use *parametrized* query and you´ll have no need in escaping at all

Comment: Follow the hint of Dmitry Bychenko , so You Prevents SQL Inject

Comment: try here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11395775/clean-the-string-is-there-any-better-way-of-doing-it

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You shouldn't be doing SQL like that, you should be using a parameterized query, check out the MSDN article, or just google it for plenty of examples.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.parameters(v=vs.110).aspx

EDIT: To clarify, as someone pointed out in your main question, doing it this way will eliminate the need to escape the characters, while also combating SQL injection from that textbox.

Comment: Sorry, my mistake (this is the first project I've done in Visual Studio, first time using Win Forms, & first time writing C#). Thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 0):

You can use pattern regex to replace characters you need.

[More Information on MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hs600312%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Use

> Uri.EscapeDataString

Method in C#

It will return an escaped output for your string.